# WebSocket. Which is correct close code for idle timeout?

Tags: websocket

Then more I research then more I think of it as a hypothetical question.

In my application I try to proceed all command frames correctly. But while building an application I've encountered one issue: NodeJS default http server closes socket after 120 seconds of inactivity. But that's fine, I can easily disable this timeout. But why not to make it actually controllable? So now I implemented an interface to adjust timeout delay. And now I have another issue: server just break the connection. Silently. That is not really good practice for WebSocket protocol, I should send close command frame first. But which status code should I provide?

Documentation describes a set of status codes, but in general they are (1) job is done, (2) server/client going down, (3) some error occurred, (4) protocol reserved:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1

And it's unclear to me, which one to choose for idle timeout? It sounds like 1001 (going away) is closer one, but I see nothing in documentation, and found no one ever asked this question.

So which one should I choose? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled too. Seems to be no answer that is easily googleable here in 2022.
In my case I've decided to go with 1002 Protocol Error, since not answering to ping is basically protocol violation